# Net work and the definitions of enthalpy and entropy and their implications in the Gibbs free energy

Tags: thermodynamics

From the first law of thermodynamics: $\Delta U = q + w$

By definition: at constante pressure: $q_P = \Delta H = \Delta U + P \Delta V \quad Eq.1$

By definition, in the reversible process: $q_{rev} = T \Delta S = \Delta U + P \Delta V$

In this way, at constante pressure and in the reversible process $\Delta H = T \Delta S$ implies that $$\Delta G^o = \Delta H - T\Delta S = 0 \quad Eq.2 $$

I think this is not true.

Now I will change the definition of $ T \Delta S$ to:

$$ T \Delta S  = \Delta U + P \Delta V - \text{(net work)}\quad Eq.3 $$

**net work**: all other kind of work: chemical, mechanical, ...

For entropy we have:

$$ \Delta H = \Delta U + P  \Delta V  \quad Eq.4 $$

Assuming that both (Eq.3 and Eq.4)  equations are true, now it's possible to write this statements:

Statement 1: At constante pressure,  **only** if $\text{(net work)} = 0 $ then $\Delta H = T \Delta S$

Statement 2: the Gibbs free energy, $\Delta G = \Delta H - T \Delta S =  \text{(net work)}$

Is the Eq.3 the true definition of entropy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $$dU = TdS+\sum_k Y_kdX_k$$ where $X_k$ and $Y_k$ are the extensive and corresponding conjugate intensive terms of the various work interactions of the system.

Introducing $G=U-TS - Y_1X_1$ where $Y_1 = p, dX_1 = -dV$ will get you $$dG = -SdT-X_1dY_1+\sum_{k'}Y_{k'}dX_{k'}$$ where $k=1,2,3...; k'=2,3,4,...$. If you now fix $T$ and $y_1$ then $dG|_{T,Y_1} = \sum_{k'}Y_{k'}dX_{k'}$, and if you have only one work interaction then $dG|_{T,Y_1}=0$
This shows that you need more than one work interaction to get nontirival result from the Lengendre transforms.

Comment: did you mean: $$dG = dU-SdT-X_1dY_1+\sum_{k'}Y_{k'}dX_{k'}$$

Comment: Forget my last comment. I understant that $$$dU = \sum_{k'}Y_{k'}dX_{k'}$$ In this way: $$dG = -SdT-X_1dY_1+\sum_{k'}Y_{k'}dX_{k'}$$

Comment: Because the pressure is a energy per volume. it's possible to define  a "pressure energy". 
This "pressure energy" is account for the value of enthalpy (H), but not for the internal energy value, U.
The main difference between the enthalpy and the internal energy is the "pressure energy": $H = U + PV$. 
However, the work associated to the change of the "pressure energy" (gas expansion or compression) is considered in the computation of the $\Delta U$.